# kNN(classifier) - Disadvantages

Tags: classification, data-mining

So I recently came along kNN k nearest neighbour.
When looking at its disadvantages, most of the literature mentions it is costly, lazy, requires full training data plus depends on the value of k and has the issue of dimensionality because of the distance.
Other than that I have following hypothesis.

1- It ignores the fact that dimensions can be inter related and instead assumes they are independent (as we are just calculating distance)
2- Has the issue of normalization of data... if the data is not normalized distance can be biased towards a specific dimension

I will like to have a comprehensive analysis on the disadvantages of kNN apart from those mentioned above and if they are wrong then why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It doesn't handle categorical variables very well
2. It doesn't handle 'soft' boundaries - i.e. areas where some cases appear on either side of a boundary.
   See also mathbabe here: https://mathbabe.org/?s=nearest+neighbor - for extended criticism.